# Integration on product probability space w.r.t. a coupled measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given two probability spaces $(X_1, \Omega_1, P_1)$ and $(X_2, \Omega_2, P_2)$, a **coupling** $P$ of $P_1$ and $P_2$ is a probability measure on $X_1\times X_2$ such that $P(A\times X_2) = P_1(A)$ and $P(X_1\times B)= P_2(B)$ for $A \in \Omega_1$ and $B \in \Omega_2$.

> If $f:X_1\to \mathbb{R}$ is an integrable function (i.e. $\int_{X_1} |f| dP_1 < +\infty$), then why is the following true? $$\int_{X_1} |f| dP_1 = \int_{X_1\times X_2} |f(x_0)| dP(x_0,x_1)$$

This follows directly from Fubini's theorem if $P$ is the product measure of $P_1$ and $P_2$; but why is it true for arbitrary couplings?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a notational curiosity - $\Omega$ is customarily used to denote a sample space and $X$ a random variable, so using $X_i$ for the sample space and $\Omega_i$ for the set of events is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $f$ is the indicator function of a measurable set, the formula holds by the assumption $P(A\times X_2)=P_1(A)$; this can be extended by linearity of the integral to linear combinations of such functions (called simple functions).

Now, each non-negative measurable function can be written as the pointwise limit of an non-decreasing sequence of simple functions. Conclude by monotone convergence.